# Analytics tracking event inside variable

Tags: php

I am trying to add add the following to a php variable...

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Driveways', 'Click through', ''. $airport .' page', , true]);"
```

something like this...

```
$airport = 'Heathrow';
$link = '<a href="http://www.awebsite.com" " onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Driveways', 'Click through', ''. $airport .' page', , true]);">A website</a>';
```

But I get an unexpected T_STRING error.  I have tried all sorts of ways to get this to work but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: It's funny because even StackOverflow sintax highlighter shows you the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the single quotes:

```
[\'_trackEvent\', \'Driveways\', \'Click through\', \''. $airport .' page\'
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quotes (note the backslashes):

```
$link = '<a href="http://www.awebsite.com" " onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Driveways\', \'Click through\', \''. $airport .' page\', , true]);">A website</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [heredoc sytnax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) too, it can look a little less noisy than escaping:

```
$link = <<<EOT 
<a href="http://www.awebsite.com" "onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Driveways', 'Click through', '$airport page', true]);">A website</a> 
EOT;
```

Answer (score -1):

Tested and worked for me

```
$extraparam="toto";
onclick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\',\'fbsharbar\',\'clicked-5\',\''.$extraparam.'\'])"
```

Comment: just before $extraparam it is simple quote not double